# Incomplete Circulant matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, circulant-matrices

The eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a Circulant matrix are well-known to be related to the discrete Fourier transform of entries of one row (the exact terms are given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix)).

My question: is there any result regarding the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of an incomplete Circulant matrix, namely, a matrix which contains the first $m<n$ rows of some $n\times n$ Circulant matrix?

Thank you!

Comment: what are the other $n-m$ rows?

Comment: Generally, the order of $n-m$ could be anything. But if you know about some results for small or large order I will be glad to hear about them. Actually, any result related to my question could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A companion matrix (see any linear algebra book) is an example
for the case $m=n-1$.

Comment: What about other cases?

Answer (score 0):

This recent paper studies the eigenvalues of special circulant matrices. Maybe it can help you.

http://www.researchgate.net/publication/269575382_Spectral_Properties_of_Circulant_Quantum_Markov_Semigroups